# How to set up UncaughtExceptionHandlers for multiple bindings in spring kafka streams?

Tags: apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream

Right now, I'm trying to access the underlying kafka streams handle by following - https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/Finchley.SR2/multi/multi__apache_kafka_streams_binder.html#_accessing_the_underlying_kafkastreams_object
Was wondering if there is a more idiomatic way to do this. Especially when there are mutliple bindings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `context.getBeansOfType(StreamsBuilderFactoryBean.class, false, false)` to get a map of `beanName:factoryBean`.

However, you should be careful not to do this too early in the context lifecycle because you may cause premature bean instantiation.

Probably best to do it in a `SmartInitializingSingleton`.

Comment: Thanks for responding, this did work! There still seems to be a potential race condition, because KafkaStreams only allows exception handlers to be set when its in CREATED state.